# Cannot send Emils over Echangewebservice (using new EWS.NETStandard-Library)

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm writing an E-Mail Automation deamon which should read a Mailbox out and send E-Mails to a specific recipient with attachments.

At the moment I only can read the Mailbox-Item and save it back with a read flag. But when I try to send an email I don't recieve an error, but the email will not be sent and I also don't see the mail nowhere on outlok online.

I try that with follow code:

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016);
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("email@domain.xx", "Password");

            service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
            email.From = new EmailAddress("email@domain.xx");
            email.ToRecipients.Add("email@domain.xx");
            email.Subject = "Hello World Test";
            email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API.");
            FolderId SentFolderForUser = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems);

            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
            email.Send();

                 //email.SendAndSaveCopy(SentFolderForUser);
```

With the old old one EWS Managed API 2.2.0 (January 2015) it works, but not with the new one (Microsoft.Exchange.WebSerivces.NETStandard v1.1.2 12/21/2017) it won't work (see the code above).

Thank you in advance for you support!

Comment: You say you get an error you need to give details of what the error is, include the trace if you have it

Comment: Hi Glen, thank you. I don't recieve any errors. It seams as you send the Email in a black hole. It never delivers to the recipient. When I use the EWS Management API 2.2.0 the same code delivers the mail to the recipients. Therefor I'm confused a llitlebit, that any error occures but you don't recieve the mail and you cannot see it in the mailbox whit web access.

Comment: Because you using the Send method rather then sendandsavecopy you won't see a copy of the Message you send in the SaveItemsFolder. I would suggest you look at using Message Trace https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200712(v=exchg.150).aspx to see what is happening

Comment: Hi Glen, I cannot see any sent email in the message trace of the admin centre. Do you have such a use case in your implementations and does a mail send work in your cases? Or does anyone have a usecase that this email sendig is working?